# How to accurately measure average temperature of a heating element?

Tags: resistors, current-measurement, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

## Problem

I'm trying to very accurately measure the heat of a nichrome wire as current is passed through it.

My approach thus far has been to monitor current and voltage across the heating element and divide them to get resistance which seems to correlate well with temp.  So far I can see a trend when the wire heats up, but it doesn't seem to have much granularity.

## Circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftekhK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schema, I'm representing the heating element as a 400mΩ resistor.  In order to measure current I've got a current sensor (represented by the AC AMP, not sure if there's a better way to do this) on the secondary coils of the transformer. To measure the voltage I'm wired in parallel to the secondary across the heating element.  I then use an offset voltage dividers to get both the outputs in the range of my microcontroller's input (0-3.3v).

## Results

So far I'm able to see a 0.1Ω difference between the hot and cold nichrome which is great, but it seems a bit noisy.

## Assumptions

I believe the first thing I need to do is get lower tolerance resistors. I see some on mouser for 0.005%.  In addition, I'm under the impression that if I decrease the resistance of my dividers, more current will flow through them and make my readings more accurate.

## Question

First, are my assumptions correct.  Second, is there a better approach?

Comment: Use a quieter power source. And a wheatstone bridge. And kelvin terminals with a current shunt resistor.

Comment: You probably want to more carefully describe what you are trying to measure than "heat", which you seem to be using to mean "temperature" but more commonly is associated with "thermal work" or "thermal power".  Use precise terminology, it will help you think about the problem.

Comment: Nichrome wire was **designed** to have a very low tempco. Can you use an alternative, preferably elemental, metal for your wire, steel for instance, which will have an order of magnitude more response.

Comment: @Neil_UK Really? Interesting. I was not aware of that. I thought it was just designed to be high resistance and corrosion resistant at high temperatures.

Comment: Where in that schematic is the 400mΩ nichrome wire?

Comment: @DKNguyen It was one of the first developed 'resistance wires', for which high resistivity, corrosion resistance at temperature and low tempco were all desired features. According to [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/rstiv.html) table at hyperphysics, its tempco is typically .0004, whereas copper, iron, tungsten (that would be a good one for high temperature work) are all around .004, an order of magnitude difference. Constantan is the approximately zero tempco wire.

Comment: Aside from the practical difficulties this will actually measure the "average" temperature of the wire. Since there will be a temperature gradient (eg it will be cooler at the ends where you connect the power source) the measured temperature will be lower than the value at the hottest part.

Comment: @Neil_UK that's an interesting idea.  I'll have to look into that. I still need the heating element to get to a ~500C is the only requirement. So I could probably do that with a different element that has a higher tempco.

Comment: @KevinWhite I should be more precise. I am looking for an average temperature

Comment: @MikeSchem Iron/steel will get to 500 for a while, but won't last anywhere near as long as nichrome would. You can buy packaged tungsten heating wires in neat transparent glass envelopes, they're called filament lamps. It depends whether you're just doing wire heating experiments, or you want something in contact with the wire.